# Можно ли «размышлять над»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов, глаголы, управление

Ходят слухи, что при проверке ЕГЭ многим экспертам дали инструкцию считать конструкции типа *писатель, **размышляя над** этой проблемой...* ошибочными. Действительно ли их использование ненормативно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы не удивился, если бы речь шла о выражении "*рассуждать над проблемой*". Размышлять "**над** проблемой" и "**о** проблеме" - не одно и то же. **Размышляет над** проблемой тот, перед кем она стоит и кому нужно её решение, а **размышлять о проблеме** может любой (как и рассуждать о ней по существу, поверхностно или праздно). По какой-то причине далеко не во всех словарях приводятся примеры сочетания с предлогом "над" (в форумах "а вот у Ушакова нет" используется как аргумент), но ни есть:

Толковый словарь русского языка Дмитриева. Д. В. Дмитриев. 2003:

> 1. Если кто-либо размышляет **над** чем-либо, о чём-либо, то это означает, что этот человек тщательно, неторопливо обдумывает что-либо, строит
>      умозаключения.

Comment: А разницу между о и над вы провели, основываясь на собственном восприятии?

Comment: На наблюдениях. Примеры названий книг (естественно, что авторы занимаются названными проблемами, а не со стороны размышляют).
Размышления над современной повестью, Владимир Ермилов, Сов. писатель, 1963
Размышления над церковным календарем 7499 года, Яков Кротов, 1994

Comment: Замечу в комментарии, что у Кузнецова есть "поразмышлять над задачей".

Answer (score 3):

[**размышля́ть**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/4495/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)
*глаг., нсв., употр. часто*
1. Если кто-либо **размышляет над чем-либо**, о чём-либо, то это означает, что этот человек тщательно, неторопливо обдумывает что-либо, строит умозаключения.
***Размышлять над своей жизнью.*** | Размышлять о современной живописи. | Размышлять об услышанном.

Мне кажется, что такое выражение вполне нормативно.

***Автор размышляет над проблемой.***
[**Клише к сочинению по русскому языку**](http://4ege.ru/russkiy/3106-klishe-k-sochineniyu-po-russkomu-yazyku.html)

***Размышлять*** (над чем?) **над проблемой** — размышляющий (над чем?) над проблемой, размышлявший (над чем?) над проблемой.
[**ЕГЭ. Русский язык. Пошаговая подготовка**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=1cl3BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BB%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=Kqj9j7v__e&sig=eqgShcZMMrL51ANdRgmWz-iNiOQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim3qP2o43cAhVFfiwKHea_AfY4ChDoAQgoMAE#v=onepage&q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BB%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9&f=false)

[**Вопрос №275187**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83)
Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как правильно: "рассуждать на тему" или "рассуждать о теме", "размышлять о проблеме" или **"размышлять над проблемой"**? Спасибо.
**Ответ** справочной службы русского языка
Возможно: размышлять о теме, проблеме; **размышлять над темой,** [над] **проблемой.**